# Compare elements of multiple vectors efficiently

Tags: c++, optimization, vector, montecarlo

EDIT: After some experimenting I think it might be this line:

```
outcomes.push_back(thesePathGatherers[j].GetResultsSoFar()[0][i]);
```

Causing issue. The implementation of those class functions are. Could getting these values back from the vector of vectors like this be slow (and slower for larger vectors)?. TheDumpOneResult function is called in "OneStepMonteCarloValuation" prior which fills the ResultList vector

```
StatisticAllPaths::StatisticAllPaths(const unsigned long minimumNumberOfPaths) : PathsDone(0)
{
    ResultList.reserve(minimumNumberOfPaths);
}

void StatisticAllPaths::DumpOneResult(double result)
{
    ResultList.push_back(result);
    PathsDone++;
}

std::vector<std::vector<double>> StatisticAllPaths::GetResultsSoFar() const
{
    vector<double> innerVector(ResultList);
    vector<vector<double> > Results(1, innerVector);
    Results[0] = ResultList;
    return Results;
}
```

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
void MonteCarloRainbowOptionFunction::ValueInstrument()
{
    std::vector<MJArray> correlatedNormVariates = GetArraysOfCorrelatedGauassiansByBoxMuller(numberOfPaths, covMatrix); 
    std::vector<StatisticAllPaths> thesePathGatherers;
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < S_vect.size(); i++)
    {
        StandardExcerciseOption thisOption(ThePayOffVect[i], TTM);
        StatisticAllPaths onePathGatherer;
        thesePathGatherers.push_back(onePathGatherer);
        OneStepMonteCarloValuation(thisOption, S_vect[i], impvol_vect[i], r, d_vect[i], numberOfPaths, correlatedNormVariates[i], thesePathGatherers[i]);
    }
    f = 0;
    std::cout << "Time check" << "\n";
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < numberOfPaths; i++)
    {       
        std::vector<double> outcomes;
        for (unsigned long j = 0; j < S_vect.size(); j++)
        {
            outcomes.push_back(thesePathGatherers[j].GetResultsSoFar()[0][i]);
        }
        switch (optionType)
        {
        case RainbowOptionType::best_of:
            f += *max_element(outcomes.begin(), outcomes.end());
            break;
        case RainbowOptionType::worst_of:
            f += *min_element(outcomes.begin(), outcomes.end());
            break;          
        default:
            throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported or unknown option type found in " + GetuniqueIdentifier()[0]);
            break;
        }   
    }
    std::cout << "Time check" << "\n";
    f *= ((double)nominal/numberOfPaths);
    return;
}
```

In the first part (before the first "Time Check") I simulate a large amount of values which gets saved in the vectors (really in the first vector of a vector of vectors) thesePathGatherers through the function OneStepMonteCarloValuation. In the second part I go through all the vectors and save the *i* element in the temp "output" vector, compare the values in output and save the result and then do the same. Looping through all the values in the thesePathGatherers. The first part runs fast but the second one takes much longer and even fails to complete all together for high enough numberOfPaths. How can I optimize this code?

Note that numberOfPaths will be *very large*

Let me know if there is more I need to share.

Comment: Maybe you should take a step back and identify the high-level algorithm problem you're trying to solve, without mentioning vectors, Monte Carlo simulation, etc.  You're describing your solution instead of the high-level problem.

Comment: What does `GetResultsSoFar()` return? Is it something pre-calculated or is it actually calculating something?

Comment: It's simply returning something pre-calculated, "OneStepMonteCarloValuation" calls the function "dumpOnePath" which calculates the values (and that isn't slow). I edited the post with the code, I think just from deduction it's probably GetResultsSoFar() causing issue still